# Language bar changed

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, language-bar

I deleted my user account and had to create a new one because it was corrupted but now my language settings have changed and the language bar doesn't work like it did before.

I can still use the Japanese ime but it can be harder to use

I have checked for updated and installed all of them so i don't think that it is because of an old version

This is what it used to look like
[image]

And this is what it looks like now
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps to see if the issue can be resolved.

Go to **Windows Settings** >  **Personalization** > **Taskbar**. Under the **Notification area** section, click **Turn system icons on or off**. Then, turn on the **Input Indicator** on this page.

[image]