# How to show system language AND keyboard layout on taskbar

Tags: windows-10, language-bar

Windows 10.

I use English input language (mostly), but a Hungarian QWERTZ keyboard.  Sometimes Windows - of course - changes my active keyboard layout without asking me.  That's not the problem I'm asking about.

I used to be able to tweak the settings so that the taskbar shows this:

```
EN
HU
```

meaning: English input language, Hungarian keyboard.  Or just EN (language and keyboard both English).

Now, for some reason, the taskbar just shows EN, and then a keyboard icon next to it - which gives no indication of which keyboard layout is active.  Have to click on it to see: more clicks, more wasted time, more distraction.

I've tried fiddling with the settings outlined in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1614456/language-bar-changed/1614835), but they don't make any difference.

Comment: How have you tweaked the settings in the past?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same question; I'm sure it used to be different.

Comment: @ElRudi: Settings, Time and Language.  Select "Language" on LHS.  Go to "Related Settings", select "Spelling, typing, keyboard...".  Go to "More Kbd settings", select "Advanced kbd settings".  In "Override for default input method", you should have the "mixed" option available.
Easy to find, eh? ;)

Answer (score 0):

My answer, currently true.  Until MS "upgrade" Win10 again so that you have to go on a totally different Magical Mystery Tour of Settings:

Settings: select Time and Language.

Select "Language" on LHS.

Go to "Related Settings", select "Spelling, typing, keyboard...".

Go to "More Kbd settings", select "Advanced kbd settings".

In "Override for default input method", you should have the "mixed languages" option available.

Easy to find, eh? ;)

Comment: I don't have the 'mixed languages' option available in that 'override for default input method' drop-down menu... See here: https://imgur.com/a/45ukE0I

Comment: Ah, it seems I found a separate issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1795250/windows-keyboard-layout-disappearing-when-extending-monitor

Answer (score 0):

Right click on taskbar, click taskbar settings. Set "Use small taskbar buttons" to off.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that either the Floating On Desktop or the Docked in the Taskbar option is chosen on the Language Bar tab of the Text Services and Input Languages dialogue box.

Comment: No, that setting just shows the Language bar _at all_.  The other option is "Hidden", which obviously I haven't selected.  "Show Text labels..." makes no difference.  "Show additional Language bar icons in the taskbar" just shows an additional invisible blob with Language bar settings.