# Windows keyboard layout disappearing when extending monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, keyboard-layout

In windows, 2 properties are connected to the keyboard: (a) the natural language in which text is being entered and (b) the layout of the keyboard being used.

The former is not very important to me, but I would like to know the latter at all times, and for this, I added the language bar to my (vertical) taskbar. In this image, the keyboard layout is shown as "US":

[image]

So far, so good.

Now my problem. When I attach an external monitor, which functions as the primary display, the language bar changes and the layout is dropped:

[image]

**Why is this and more importantly, what can I do to fix it??**

I've noticed that using the taskbar in the horizontal position does not have the issue on either display, but I'm looking to keep the vertical orientation.

[image]

I've also noticed that using the display at 100% scaling (instead of the recommended 150%) solves the issue, but I'm old and my eyes are not good enough for 100%. Maybe I should just go back to 640x480 and call it a day.

Comment: This may be adjusting for differences in resolution between your main monitor and your external monitor.

Comment: Yes, it's probably something silly like that, though it IS showing in the horizontal taskbar on that same external monitor. Do you have a suggestion, how I can fix it?

Comment: No; that's usually the sort of thing that Microsoft decides "it's better to do it our way", and in Windows 10, that usually means "and you can't do it your way, either.". I initially thought that the only way you were going to get the taskbar off the bottom at all was with an unsupported hack, in which case "all bets are off", but when I checked, the ability to put the task bar on any edge is in fact a legitimate setting in Settings...

Comment: If it _is_ a function of resolution, all I could suggest is to set all monitors to their respective "recommended" resolution, which is the highest that they support, but that doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. They are at that resolution already ‍♂️ The scaling is at the recommended 150%, which actually is part of the issue - at 100%, the issue disappears. This windows is wearing me down, but unfortunately, I can't use anything else at my work.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't thought of the scaling issue; that effectively reduces the resolution, and since I like my screen to be information-dense, I just routinely set the display scale to 100%, so that particular issue doesn't actually occur to me 